# collection-repeat and ion-option-button issues (again!)

Tags: list, sockets, ionic-framework

I am currently writing an application using socket.io and ionic. I have to handle a list of 6000 people so I've decide to use collection-repeat and swipe + ion-option-button to verify items (remove then from the list)
The names on the list can be removed and the changes will be broadcasted to the rest of apps using sockets so everyone will have their own list updated in real-time
But if If the list change, each row is assigned new data but the html stays the same, including the state of the swiped button!

Here is a screen recording of the bug: https://youtu.be/15oZj7G1DQ0

You can see the list shrinking because another user is removing items from the list and broadcasting to me through websockets, but the button doesn't move along with the item and just stays in the same place.

The problem doesn't happen with ng-repeat but I can't use ng-repeat for this.
And I can't use $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons() to go around the problem because it can be really annoying for the users.

There is any possible solution for this?

resumed code sample:

1) people controller

```
$rootScope.verify = function(){

    this.person.verified = true;

    //broadcast to main controller
    $rootScope.$broadcast('verify', this.person)
}
```

2) Main Controller (aka socket controller)

```
  $rootScope.$on('verify', function(e, person) {
    //send to socket server
    socket.emit('event:verify', person); 
  });

  //incoming data from the socket server
  socket.on('event:incoming',function(personData){

    var person = $filter('filter')($scope.people, {id: personData.id}, true)[0];        
    var key = $scope.people.indexOf(person);

    $scope.people[key].verified = personData.verified;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you look at this example: http://play.ionic.io/app/a8d986cdaf19

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    I love kittens!
    <ion-option-button ng-if="item" class="button-positive">Share</ion-option-button>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive">Edit</ion-option-button>

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-toggle ng-model="item">
  Show Delete?
</ion-toggle>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can use ng-if to show or hide a optoin button, so you can broadcast a event when a item is removed and hide the option button with a variable that you can toggle based on the event.

```
 $scope.$emit('objectRemoved');
```

and then:

```
$scope.$on('objectedRemoved', function(){
    $scope.variableToControlVerifyButton = false;
})
```

if you post your code I may be able to help more but I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: That's not really the problem... I am doing that already when I "verify" a person on the list, the problem is when someone with the same application broadcast the changes to me via websockets, the list is updated automatically in real-time.

Comment: Jess, I updated the post with some code sample, the problem lives on item 2, after I update the scope using collection-repeat only

Comment: I think I have to stop the list to be updated if I swipe the button... this should do for now, but would be nice to find a better solution.